# Trying a very simple sum macro

Tags: vba, sum

I'm trying to perform a simple sum function which lets me define the range beforehand, but I get a #NAME? error.

```
Sub SumSelectedRange()
Dim ThisRng As Range
Set ThisRng = Application.InputBox("Select a range", "Get Range", Type:=8)
ActiveCell.Formula = "=SUM(ThisRng)"
End Sub
```

What's wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using a range or any other vba reference it must be out side the quotes.

Like this:

```
Sub SumSelectedRange()
Dim ThisRng As Range
Set ThisRng = Application.InputBox("Select a range", "Get Range", Type:=8)
ActiveCell.Formula = "=SUM(" & ThisRng.Address & ")"
End Sub
```